# iframe calls by user or server

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am quite new to web programming and trying to get my head around iframes.

So, let us say I have an iframe on my webpage (which is on a server) to the popular bbc site as follows:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk"></iframe>
```

Now, when the user goes to my page, the iframe loads - but, who is making the calls within the iFrame? (i.e the BBC content?) Is it my server or the user?

I guess another way to ask the question is who's IP will bbc's log see in this case? the web servers or the users IP?

Stupid question I suppose, but I just am confused!

Comment: It is requested from the browser, so it will be the user's IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's web browser would still be making the request.

You can use your browser's developer tools to see this happen and confirm (they usually pop up by pressing F12). Please become comfortable with them as they will be one of your trusty tools for web development in the future. :)

So to answer your question. Regardless of where the page holding the iframe lives, ultimately the user is still making the request therefore their IP should show up.

Comment: Thanks Cesar for your explanation - accepted your answer. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your visitor's browser will simply get a whole HTML page from your server and after that it's up to the browser to make do. As a result, all calls like external scripts or images but also iframes will be made by the client.